There is no sound after recording the video on the current page on the H5 side?
I have a question. We have a video face-to-face interview scenario that requires video and audio collection. In this scenario, the user enters the room after clicking the link. There is only one user in the room. There are some face-to-face interview questions on our page that require the user to answer. After the user actively clicks "Start", the question will be broadcasted by voice for the user to answer. After "Start", the video will also be recorded. The questions that the user needs to answer are realized by our self-developed text-to-audio conversion and then playing the converted audio.
The current problem is that after the video is successfully recorded, when we preview the video in the Tencent Cloud background, we find that there is only the sound of the user answering the question in the video, but no voice broadcasting of the question. During the recording process, the voice broadcast is normal, but I don’t know why the sound played on the web page cannot be collected. We tested it many times and found that there is a part of the broadcast sound in the video about 10 seconds before, and then there is no sound. I am very confused.
I want to confirm whether our application scenario supports single-person single video recording and audio collection? Is there any problem with voice broadcast under iOS? Thank you！

You can try to broadcast the voice of the question by trtc.startPlugin('AudioMixer', options) method，this method support to play local audio file or audio track by transfer different parameter，through this method the background audio can be recorded。
More details you can refer the following document ： https://web.sdk.qcloud.com/trtc/webrtc/v5/doc/en/tutorial-22-advanced-audio-mixer.html
